# MySql - SubQuery is not working properly

Tags: mysql, subquery, mysql-dependent-subquery

BubQuery always return the empty result if the query is correct.

**1st Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE user_age IN(1,22,34);
```

**Result:**

[image]

**2nd Query:**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_age_list) AS user_age FROM `user_detail` WHERE id='1';
```

**Result:**
[image]

**I am try:**

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE user_age IN(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_age_list) AS user_age FROM `user_detail` WHERE id='1');
```

**Sqlfiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com./#!9/d6515f/3 //This is a sample table.

Above the query is always return the empty rows. 
But each of query return the result if its run single.
Really I don't know where is the error.
Please update the answer or suggest me.

Comment: See normalization. Normalize your schema. If the problem persists, then see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: get rid of the group concat. just select user_age_list form user_detail.

Comment: Please use **Sqlfiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com./#!9/d6515f/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid Use of GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT * 
FROM `user` 
WHERE user_age IN(SELECT user_age_list FROM `user_detail` WHERE id='1');
```

**UPDATED**

```
SELECT * 
FROM `user` u 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `user_detail` ud  WHERE id='1' AND ud.user_age_list = u.user_age)
```

Comment: Return the empty result.

Comment: what kind of data present in `user_age_list` column?

Comment: SubQuery will return "12234" Without GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: "12234" as single value or each age on separate row

Comment: Your subquery will return this value. `user_age_list` as separate row.

Comment: if this is so then this should work since this query become equivalent to your first query

Comment: It's retun realy empty.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE user_age IN(1,22,34);` It return the result without subquery.

Comment: This solution also return the empty result.

Comment: I have gone through SqlFiddle it seem thats my first solution giving result what u looking for

Comment: Sorry I was try to UPDATED query only. It's working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM user
WHERE user_age IN 
(SELECT user_age_list user_age 
 FROM user_detail
 WHERE id='1');
```

You don't need the group concat here.  The engine knows the result set is an inclusive list without the group concat.

What it is trying to do is compare the '1,22,34' to each user_age which is why you get no results.

```
1 <> '1,22,34'
22 <> '1,22,34'
34 <> '1,22,34'
```

thus no results.

Comment: It's return the empty rows.It consider the single value within single quotes.

Comment: What is the result if you `SELECT * FROM user_detail WHERE user_age_list IN(1,22,34)`;?  It seems to me the problem may be how the data is structured in that table then...

Comment: I am getting this result: `1,22,34`

Comment: Then the where clause of  `WHERE ID = '1'` is causing no records to be returned from the subquery.  Why do you need ID=1 in the user_age_list?  At this point I would need to see this behavior as a SQLFiddle.com.  I can't imange why this or @JayDipJ 's solution is not working